# Where was Kolashine, Russia?

Tags: poland, russia, historical-gazetteer, place-names

I am researching my great-grandmother. In a naturalization form on 1936-04-23, she listed her place and date of birth as Kolashine, Russia, 1888-11-09.

Source: https://www.ancestry.com/imageviewer/collections/2280/images/31301_168428-00442

Where is Kolashine, Russia?

The only thing close to this that I've found is Kolasin, Montenegro, but this area has never been a part of Russia, so I guess that must not be the same place. Her husband was Polish (from the disputed Russian-Poland division area) so I thought perhaps it was in this same area, but I've searched google, ancestry.com, and oldmapsonline.org and found no results.

Following the advice on [FamilyTree's wiki section for Russian Poland](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Poland_Gazetteers#Russian_Poland), I checked the relevant section of the 1877 Gazetteer of the Kingdom of Poland, but didn't find anything that looked like a match.

[image]

Source: https://www.sbc.org.pl/dlibra/publication/11404/edition/10794/content?ref=desc

Comment: I’m also looking at old family records, and coming across the exact same city. Did you ever figure anything out about this?

Comment: @DavidRigden you and I are cousins. I do not know why the user below suggested it but it turns out he was right, I found our ancestors' records in Kałuszyn. You can check out my family tree on ancestry.com for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybeit is Kaluszyn, near Warsaw

Comment: Welcome to G&FH. Can you explain a little more about why you think this is the right answer?

Answer (score 2):

Phonetically, my immediate guess was [Kalyazin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalyazin) in Tver' oblast, Russia. (However this town is north of Moscow and not very close to Poland.)